# Python Pandas merge samed name columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a few CSV files I'm trying to work with, but some of them have multiple columns with the same name.

For example I could have a csv like this:

```
ID   Name   a    a    a     b    b
1    test1  1    NaN  NaN   "a"  NaN
2    test2  NaN  2    NaN   "a"  NaN
3    test3  2    3    NaN   NaN  "b"
4    test4  NaN  NaN  4     NaN  "b"
```

loading into pandasis giving me this:

```
ID   Name   a    a.1  a.2   b    b.1
1    test1  1    NaN  NaN   "a"  NaN
2    test2  NaN  2    NaN   "a"  NaN
3    test3  2    3    NaN   NaN  "b"
4    test4  NaN  NaN  4     NaN  "b"
```

What I would like to do is merge those same name columns into 1 column (if there are multiple values keeping those values separate) and my ideal output would be this

```
ID   Name   a      b  
1    test1  "1"    "a"   
2    test2  "2"    "a"
3    test3  "2;3"  "b"
4    test4  "4"    "b"
```

So wondering if this is possible?

Comment: You need `df.columns=['ID', 'Name', 'a','a','a','b','b']` to get the `DataFrame` to be like the 1st one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `groupby` on `axis=1`, and experiment with something like

```
>>> def sjoin(x): return ';'.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))
>>> df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.apply(sjoin, axis=1))
  ID   Name        a  b
0  1  test1      1.0  a
1  2  test2      2.0  a
2  3  test3  2.0;3.0  b
3  4  test4      4.0  b
```

where instead of using `.astype(str)`, you could use whatever formatting operator you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Probably it is not a good idea to have duplicated column names, but it will work:

```
In [72]:

df2=df[['ID', 'Name']]
df2['a']='"'+df.T[df.columns.values=='a'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(["%i"%item for item in x[x.notnull()]]))+'"' #these columns are of float dtype
df2['b']=df.T[df.columns.values=='b'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join([item for item in x[x.notnull()]])) #these columns are of objects dtype
print df2
   ID   Name      a    b
0   1  test1    "1"  "a"
1   2  test2    "2"  "a"
2   3  test3  "2;3"  "b"
3   4  test4    "4"  "b"

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 5):

Of course DSM and CT Zhu have marvelously concise answers that utilize a lot built in features of Python in general and dataframe in particular. Here's something a little -- [cough] -- verbose.

```
def myJoiner(row):
    newrow = []
    for r in row:
        if not pandas.isnull(r):
            newrow.append(str(r))
    return ';'.join(newrow)

def groupCols(df, key):
    columns = df.select(lambda col: key in col, axis=1)
    joined = columns.apply(myJoiner, axis=1)
    joined.name = key
    return pandas.DataFrame(joined)

import pandas 
from io import StringIO  # python 3.X
#from StringIO import StringIO #python 2.X

data = StringIO("""\
ID   Name   a    a    a     b    b
1    test1  1    NaN  NaN   "a"  NaN
2    test2  NaN  2    NaN   "a"  NaN
3    test3  2    3    NaN   NaN  "b"
4    test4  NaN  NaN  4     NaN  "b"
""")

df = pandas.read_table(data, sep='\s+')
df.set_index(['ID', 'Name'], inplace=True)


AB = groupCols(df, 'a').join(groupCols(df, 'b'))
print(AB)
```

Which gives me:

```
                a  b
ID Name             
1  test1      1.0  a
2  test2      2.0  a
3  test3  2.0;3.0  b
4  test4      4.0  b
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on one of the previous answers:
The columns come in from read_csv with suffixes on the columns to make them unique, as you've noticed a.0, a.1, a.2 etc.

You may need to pass a function to group_by in order to cater for this e.g.:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') #csv file with multiple columns of the same name

#function to join columns if column is not null
def sjoin(x): return ';'.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))

#function to ignore the suffix on the column e.g. a.1, a.2 will be grouped together
def groupby_field(col):
    parts = col.split('.')
    return '{}'.format(parts[0])

df = df.groupby(groupby_field, axis=1,).apply(lambda x: x.apply(sjoin, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to patch the Dataframe, you could do:

```
# consolidated columns, replacing instead of joining by ;
s_fixed_a = df['a'].fillna(df['a.1']).fillna(df['a.2'])
s_fixed_b = df['b'].fillna(df['b.1'])
# create new df
df_resulting = df[['Id', 'Name']].merge(s_fixed_a, left_index=True, right_index=True).merge(s_fixed_b, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```