# Merge values in next row pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframes:

[this are tables I am trying to merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVrJM.png)

[and this is the result I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfrum.png)

So, I want merged values not to be on the same row.

When I try to merge like that:

```
pd.merge(a,b,how='inner', on=['date_install','device_os'])
```

it merges values in one raw.

Please,suggest how it can be resolved

Comment: So need `df = pd.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True)` ?

Comment: If yes, it is dupe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36526282/2901002)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df1.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
```

or by using [concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index = True)
```

or using [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
df.merge(df1, how = 'outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24391268/3748167 (probable duplicate)

The only difference here is concatenating both dataframes first and then applying rest of the logic.

`def sjoin(x): 
    return ';'.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))
pd.concat([a,b]).groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.apply(sjoin, axis=1))`