# merge columns with same name , their values seperated by comma in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am beginner in pandas. I have one query, Let's say i have one df which is input as

```
sno y   x   x    x
1   47 abs owi  pyt
2   57 uyh jig  ojt
3   84 urr isj  ieh
```

and the output should be like

```
sno  y   x
1   47 abs,owi,pyt
2   57 uyh,jig,ojt
3   84 urr,isj,ieh
```

Thanks for the solution in advanced

Comment: if first column is the index you can do `df.agg(','.join,1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas merge samed name columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390645/python-pandas-merge-samed-name-columns-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: i have tried that but that is not working for me