# Pandas / Groupby / Apply Optimization

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a piece of code trying to merge cols. with duplicated cols names in a pandas structure, basically I am trying to do the same thing like this post:

[Python Pandas merge samed name columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390645/python-pandas-merge-samed-name-columns-in-a-dataframe)

However, the DataFrame I am trying to process, is loaded from a CSV which is around 1GB, and has around 2600 columns & 27000+ rows.

The code runs, but it runs for ~2hr20min.

Out of 2600 columns, only ~30 of cols needs to be merged into 4 cols, say from 13th~42nd.

Is there a way to optimize the code mentioned in the linked posts? Perhaps find a way to tell  Pandas just to GroupBy cols from 13th~42nd, and join only the fields in this area.

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: The user guide show how to slice columns with labels or list-type integer indexing using `.loc[]` and `.iloc[]` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label

Comment: Take a look at `.melt()` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt   after melting target columns into variable & value columns and `.dropna(subset=['value'])` you can `.groupby(['variable']).apply(';'.join)` as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27298308/6692898

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RichieV for both tips. I ended up using both tips and I ended up doing this:

1st section out your dataset into 2 parts by cols, I did it at 25 because that's where the repeating cols with NaN values end:

```
    sec1 = filtered_data.iloc[:,:25]
    sec2 = filtered_data.iloc[:,25:]
```

Then you melt the 1st part of the data-frame into into variable & value cols while preserving header_cols, this is faster than melting the whole data-frame:

```
    sec1 = sec1.melt(id_vars=header_cols)
```

Next you just dropna for any rows that has empty values in any cols, mainly will be in value col:

```
    sec1 = sec1.dropna(axis='index', how='any') #remove rows with empty fields
```

Finally pivot it back and join the 2 split data-frames:

```
    sec1 = sec1.pivot_table(index= header_cols,
                   columns='variable',
                   values='value',
                   aggfunc='first')
    sec1 = sec1.reset_index()
    sec1 = sec1.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    filtered_data = p.concat([sec1, sec2], axis=1)
```

Thanks RichieV once again for the great tips!