# How do I combine the values in a column with the same column name without having to rename the column names (like what pandas does)

Tags: python, r, excel, pandas, dataframe

so I have a csv file as below but with 1300 columns

| id | Date | A | A | B | B | B | B | C | C | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2009 | Y |  |  |  | Y |  |  |  |  |
| B | 2009 | Y |  | Y | Y | Y |  |  |  |  |
| C | 2011 | Y | Y |  |  |  |  |  | Y | Y |
| D | 2013 |  | Y |  | Y | Y |  |  |  |  |
| E | 2015 |  |  |  |  |  | Y | Y |  | Y |
| F | 2017 |  |  |  | Y |  |  | Y | Y |  |

I want to combine the column values of all columns that have the same column name to look like below:

| id | Date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2009 | Y | Y |  |
| B | 2009 | Y,Y | Y,Y,Y |  |
| C | 2011 | Y,Y |  | Y,Y |
| D | 2013 | Y | Y,Y |  |
| E | 2015 |  | Y | Y,Y |
| F | 2017 |  | Y | Y,Y |

I've been searching on how to combine columns with same column names in excel, r and python, but most of the samples either involve summing up the numerical values instead of concatenating strings or have duplicate rows instead of columns.

I've tried the following code I saw on Stackoverflow

```
pd.concat(x for _, x in df.groupby(df.columns.duplicated(), axis=1))
```

But for some reason, I get this output:

| id | Date | A | A.1 | B | B.1 | B.2 | B.3 | C | C.1 | C.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2009 | Y |  |  |  | Y |  |  |  |  |
| B | 2009 | Y |  | Y | Y | Y |  |  |  |  |
| C | 2011 | Y | Y |  |  |  |  |  | Y | Y |
| D | 2013 |  | Y |  | Y | Y |  |  |  |  |
| E | 2015 |  |  |  |  |  | Y | Y |  | Y |
| F | 2017 |  |  |  | Y |  |  | Y | Y |  |

I feel like this should be easy, but I can't seem to find a solution around this.

Comment: Can you please provide the input data in a form that's easier to create a df from? Setting up the df takes longer than to answer the question.

Comment: Also, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390645/python-pandas-merge-samed-name-columns-in-a-dataframe) answer your question?

Comment: @timgeb - not really - because I just realised that pandas changes the column name (hence the A.1, A.2, B.1, B.2) to make it unique - which I then have to revert the column names back to old names (that's 1300 of them). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Thanks @Pygirl for making them into tables. I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: Use `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]` first for remove values after `.`

Comment: @jezrael that worked. I think I was going about it the long way. Thank you both!

Comment: Why is this tagged with R and Excel if it's only about Python?

Comment: Hi @camille, because I was also trying to filter the data using R dplyr and excel consolidate. Nothing was working at the time - so I just tagged all 3.