# How to reshape a dataframe with identical column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-melt

I  want to reshape this table:

| Back Vowels | x | x | x | y | y | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a: | -26.69 | -40.06 | -49.59 | -15.56 | -7.5 | -11.89 |
| o: | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

to the following format:

| Back Vowels | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a: | -26.69 | -15.56 |
| a: | -40.06 | -7.5 |
| a: | -49.59 | -11.89 |
| o: | ... | .... |

What pandas function should I use?

Thank you!:)

I am having trouble formulating the right question, I looked into `pivot_table()`, `melt()`, and `stack()`, but they seem to be doing other stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas merge samed name columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390645/python-pandas-merge-samed-name-columns-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: That link is a different question because they're aggregating cells (e.g. notice how column `a` of `test3` shows a combined `2;3`)

Comment: For Elena's question: `df.set_index('Back Vowels').T.groupby(level=0).agg(list).T.explode(['x', 'y'])`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you got multiple columns with same name, so i supposed that come from some kind of merge.
This input make the following output

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Back Vowels': ["a:", "o:"],
                   'x': [-26.69,"..."],
                   'y': [-15.56,"..."],})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Back Vowels': ["a:", "o:"],
                   'x': [-40.06,"..."],
                   'y': [-11.89,"..."],})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Back Vowels': ["a:", "o:"],
                   'x': [-49.59,"..."],
                   'y': [-7.5,"..."],})

df = pd.merge(pd.merge(df,df2,'inner','Back Vowels'),df3,'inner', 'Back Vowels')

df= df.rename(columns={"x_x": "x", "x_y": "x", "y_x": "y" , "y_y": "y"})
```

Output:

```
     Back Vowels       x    y           x     y        x    y
0         a:      -26.69    -15.56  -40.06  -11.89  -49.59  -7.5
1         o:         ...    ...      ...    ...      ...    ...
```

This function will merge columns with same names together:

```
def same_merge(x): return ','.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))
```

Apply the function :

```
df_new = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.apply(same_merge, axis=1))
```

Make the columns be arrays :

```
df_new['x'] = df_new['x'].str.split(",")
df_new['y'] = df_new['y'].str.split(",")
```

Finally explode the columns to get desired output:

```
df_final = df_new.explode(list('xy')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Final output:

```
   Back Vowels       x         y
0    a:           -26.69    -15.56
1    a:           -40.06    -11.89
2    a:           -49.59    -7.5
3    o:              ...    ...
4    o:              ...    ...
5    o:              ...    ...
```